# adding some text into message in mail

Tags: php, email

```
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = 'Ձեզ գրել են ձեր կայքից';
$to = 'stereoshoots@gmail.com';
$headers = "From: ".$email;
mail($to,$sub,$message,$headers);
```

I got $contactname (client name). My task is the text like this :

From : $contactname

$message (the text that client wrote).

How should i implant name into text?

Comment: Do you just mean `$message = "From: $contactname \n $message";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can costumise, the below, but `from contact name` is in this case, `$from`

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Ձեզ գրել են ձեր կայքից";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
echo "Mail Sent.";}
else{
echo "Mail not sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: $contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = "Ձեզ գրել են ձեր կայքից";
$to = "bulbulator2007@mail.ru";
$headers = "From: ".$email;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
echo "sent!";
}
else {
echo "not sent!";
}
Why im not getting the email?

Comment: To check if your webserver is sending mail, copy the above code, change `$to` to your email, and refresh the page, once, it you get the email, then we can talk about other things assuming already your web server is working.  @Marker

Comment: Everything is ok with sending now thanks! But i got some problem with charset. The text, that client send is armenian. And when im trying to send text in armenian language i get  у│у╔у╕ уёж─у╔у╛ у╖у│у╔у╕ уёж─у╔у╛ у╖у│у╔у╕ уёж─у╔у╛ у╖. How can i solve this charset problem ?

Comment: Well, check if the receiver of the mail's browser can actually render the language, other than that, I can't say much, because, it works for me. Maybe, you should open a new question about that.